# ffmpeg error - reference frames exceeds max, video is mp4 from matlab

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing

I'm saving videos in matlab as mpeg-4 (using VideoWriter) and when I open them in my media player they seem to be working (albeit not the best quality). 
However, when I'm loading them into another piece of code that uses ffmpeg I'm getting a bunch of errors as seen here:

```
[h264 @ 0000000000E0BED0] number of reference frames (0+2) exceeds max (1; proba
bly corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 00000000072B0A80] number of reference frames (0+2) exceeds max (1; proba
bly corrupt input), discarding one
```

When using ffprobe, this is the output I get:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'YDXJ0113_left.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
  Duration: 00:00:19.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10733 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x720 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 8:9], 10725 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 239762 tbn, 479524 tbc (de
fault)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks. Edited and changed into code